# Async celery tasks overhead

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, gunicorn, flask-mail

I am using this code to send notifications for some thousands of emails. It seems like it create some overhead in the web server (gunicorn) just after running the for loop. When sending the emails everything is fine.

```
users = User.query.all()

for user in users:
    send_email_celery(user.email, gettext(u'New email'), 'users/email/new_data', #plus some parameters)
```

So I am thinking about use BCC but then I realize I can't since each user has a unique uuid unsubscribe and the BCC has some limits in the mail clients.

So, what is the correct way to handle this type of action with bulk mails ?

```
@celery.task
def send_async_email_celery(msg):
    mail.send(msg)
 
def send_email_celery(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    countdown = kwargs.get('countdown', 600)
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(subject, sender=app.config['MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    send_async_email_celery.apply_async(args=[msg], countdown=countdown)
```

---

```
gunicorn --error-logfile gunicorn-error.log --timeout 600 --max-requests 500 --max-requests-jitter 50 --workers 5 app:app -b localhost:8080
```

---

EDIT 1: after some debugging using top, cpu is not full load. Is something else that halt temporarily gunicorn during some seconds.

EDIT 2: after the changes based on the answer of 2ps now the loop is fast, but the web server is still locked some seconds after the loop execution.

EDIT 3: Try to change rabbitmq to reddis, same problem. Ignoring results, same problem.

EDIT 4: After moving the loop of users to the @celery route, the problem still persists

EDIT 5: The issue has been solved by using gevent worker.

Comment: defer the loop to celery as well, otherwise you lock the thread to create 1 celery task per user, and during that time the webserver cannot serve any request.

Comment: @AnthonyPerot the server response after the loop is almost instantaneous now. However after some seconds gunicorn will get halt, that is the initial issue. I don't know how to debug this honestly

Comment: Pulling in all users in one go doesn't look all right. Also doing this on a server side also doesn't look good. So you should have a celery task that you should initiate from your webserver and then you should have task initiate other send email tasks. Also you should use pagination while pulling all the users from DB. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html. Next why are you pulling all the fields when you are using only email? You should lower the footprint of your user query

Answer (score 1):

The html email rendering is the overhead -- if you want to make this go faster for the caller, move the template rendering inside the celery task.

```
@celery.task
def send_async_email_celery(subject, from_, to_, template, **kwargs):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=from_, recipients=[to_])
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    mail.send(msg)
 
def send_email_celery(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    countdown = kwargs.get('countdown', 600)
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    from_ = app.config['MAIL_SENDER']
    send_async_email_celery.apply_async(args=[subject, from_, to, template], kwargs=kwargs, countdown=countdown)
```

Comment: After hours of refactoring, now the loop is fast but I have the same problem.